# Flickering with Ubuntu 16.04 on Mid-2015 MacBook Pro Retina 15-inch

Tags: intel-graphics, macbook-pro, gpu-driver

For 3 months or so my MBP was fine under Ubuntu.  About a month ago (I think after an update), my screen started flickering whenever there is a screen refresh.  The flickering varies from slight jitter to split-second screen tearing.  It is hard to work with.

I found that if I attach an external monitor via HDMI the screen flicker stops on both monitors.

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

I tried getting the appropriate 16.04 Intel drivers from 01.org, but I still have the same problem.
**Edit from comment:**
If I boot or come out of suspend with the power cable disconnected, the flicker doesn't happen. I can then plug in the power cable and there is no flicker. Also, this problem does not happen under OSX/MacOS

Comment: This is my problem too. Works fine with connected displays, and often if it's plugged in, but flickers constantly. Doing something like running TuxRacer or opening a Twitch stream seems to temporarily abate it but is of course horrible for battery life.

Comment: Try adding `i915.enable_fbc=0` to the boot parameters in GRUB

Comment: it's a common problem. The answer is not hard to find (happended to me last year, took 20 mins of research to fix).

Comment: Can you duplicate the problem when booted from live media?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding`acpi_osi=` to boot parameters. Installing the package `xbacklight` might also help