# Macbook second display screen flicker

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook

I'm using a Macbook Pro that I'm dual booting to Ubuntu.  Recently (within the last month) I have started to experience a screen flicker randomly every couple of minutes.  A colleague of mine is also experiencing the same thing.

Some notes:

- I'm using an external monitor connected through a thunderbolt->DVI
  dongle with the laptop lid closed.
- If the laptop is open (so that 2
  screens are in use), there is no flickering

Should I raise this as a bug or is this an issue with my configuration?

Edit:

- I have recently experienced the same flickering without using an external monitor at all.  The workaround suggested (to boot without the power cable) seems to help with this also.

Comment: I had a macbook and used an external screen. The only time I saw this was when the connection to the external screen was loose. The flicker coincided with computer switching momentarily to main screen.

Comment: @BenjaminBrink, thanks for the suggestion, which connection was loose? (Thunderbolt, DVI on dongle or DVI on the monitor)

Comment: The connection between macbook and dongle. There are a few connectors on the side. It tends to be one of the first to work loose, perhaps because of its narrow, boxy profile.

Comment: To be clear, that's the Thunderbolt connection.

Comment: I just remembered that I tried the external monitor with mac os and there is no problem with flickering there...so probably not related to the connector.

Comment: The only other time I've seen flickering was due to a wire's insulation splitting away from wire in the hinge section between screen and main board. (This link suggests this may be a weakness in the design: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-fix-my-screen-flickering.682050/#post-7421108 ) I replaced the wire using my electronics experience and soldering tools, and following some ifixit directions on how to replace screen (which I didn't need to do) to disassemble and reassemble unit.

Comment: Maybe the time you tried with OSX and external monitor wasn't long enough for problem to show. In any case, best wishes. If I can think of anything else, will post again.

Comment: Are there any indications in system logs /var/log ?

Comment: I feel like it's not the hardware since: 1) My colleague seemed to get the problem at the same time, 2) The problem is not seen with OSX, 3) If I open the lid of my laptop there is no more flickering on the second display.  About messages in /var/log, is there anything specific that I should look for?

Comment: Mark the time when flickering occurs, and see if any log activity can be associated with it.. repeat patterns.. No sense ruling out anything at this point.

Comment: I used the workaround from Chris for a while.  Now, after some software updates the problem is gone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't answer, but might be a workaround.  I have similar problem with my MacBook Pro, only it is on the built-in display.  It goes away if I:

- Plug in an external monitor
- Boot/come out of suspend with the power cable disconnected.  I can then connect the power and there is no flicker.

[My similar post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873438/flickering-with-ubuntu-16-04-on-mid-2015-macbook-pro-retina-15-inch)

Comment: Well, I love that you've removed my annoying flickering.  So even though it's not a proper solution I will give the answer to you for saving my sanity ;)